# should the contaner calculate the height for me?

Tags: html, css, css-float

i have one div that contain three div for a part in my website
code is like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div ></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div1"></div></div>
```

in css :

```
#container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 950px;
opacity: .5;
filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
background: #fff;}

#div1 {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background: black;
float: left;}

#div2 {
margin:50px 0 50px 0;
width: 950px;
float: left;}

#div3 {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 437px;
height: 532px;
margin: 18px;
float: left;}
```

when i remove the `float:left` form the #container 
then it's height will not be zero using firefox
but when i add it back,it'll work correctly but i can not center the boy in browser window.

how can i fix this?

Comment: check the html code
div one   : no ID
div two   : DIV1
div three : DIV1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a clear div. That will allow your container to adapt to the height of the floated elements. Also you had some errors in your CSS.

"#." is not how you declare an ID.

Additionally, the ID in your HTML needs to match the ID in your CSS 100%, case sensitive. In your HTML you had `id="contianer"`, but in your css, `#container`

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
    height:0!important
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    background: #fff;
}
#div1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
    float: left;
}

#div2 {
    margin:50px 0 50px 0;
    width: 950px;
    float: left;
}

#div3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 437px;
    height: 532px;
    margin: 18px;
    float: left;
}

<div id="container">
    <div ></div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple explanation.

Floating an element means you take it out of the normal flow of elements, and non-floated elements **will not make room for it**.

Thus, when a container only has child elements which are `float`ed, the container **will not** take the height or width of its children.

To make this work intuitively, meaning making the container take the width and height of its children, you can either `float` the container, or use one of the [several methods for clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

My preferred solution is to use `overflow: hidden` on the container, if floating it doesn't work in your scenario. `overflow: hidden` will work in most simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using float: left...use display:inline;

```
<style>
  #container{margin:0 auto;width:950px;opacity: .5;filter: alpha(opacity = 50);background: #fff;text-align:center;}
  #container div{display:inline;}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
    <div class="div3">Div 3</div>
</div>
```